# BiometricPrompt builder system UI type

Tags: android, security, android-biometric-prompt

I am working on authenticating my my via **BiometricPrompt**

The UI shown by system varies

on Motorola (stock Android) I get BottomSheet

on OnePlus I get Full screen activity

How can I know what type of UI would be shown Or how can I control the ui

**My problem**

Facing a big issue in Activity transition

In BottomSheet UI I can see the my app screen UI elements which I don't want

I can't guess how GooglePay(Tez) is doing

**MyCode**

```
val executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity)
            val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(activity, executor,
                object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                    override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)

                        if (errorCode == BiometricConstants.ERROR_USER_CANCELED) {
                            listener.onAuthCancelled()
                        } else {
                            listener.onAuthFailed()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                        listener.onAuthSucceeded()
                    }

                    override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                        super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                        listener.onAuthFailed()
                    }
                })

            val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setSubtitle("Sub title ")
                .setConfirmationRequired(false)
                .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
                .build()

            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
```

Comment: are you saying the Motorola doesn't have a scrim? Also are you using the AndroidX Biometric support library https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric ?

Comment: @IsaiDamier :  here is my learning https://medium.com/@karthik_78204/authenticating-okcredit-app-via-keyguard-mannager-not-biometric-api-d1b3c03d23ad?source=friends_link&sk=b639d8cb3ad2a4c36becdaa3bc968318